# C# Dictionary unexpectedly returning null

Tags: c#, dictionary, null

Let's say I have this code:

```
public static class Converters {
  public static Dictionary<Unit, Dictionary<string, Func<float, float>>> ConverterDictionary =
    new Dictionary<Unit, Dictionary<string, Func<float, float>>> 
    {
        {
            Unit.MS, new Dictionary<string, Func<float, float>>() {
                {"m/s -> km/h", MStoKMH },
                {"m/s -> mph", MStoMPH }
            }
        }
    };

    private static Func<float, float> MStoKMH = val => val * 3.6f;
    private static Func<float, float> MStoMPH = val => val * 2.23693629f;
}

public enum Unit {
    MS
}
```

And I somewhere else try to retrieve the `MStoKMH` function from the `ConverterDictionary` (and invoke it) using this code:

```
Func<float, float> test = Converters.ConverterDictionary[Unit.MS]["m/s -> km/h"];
float x = test(5);
```

but the last line throws a NPE ("test was null"). Why my code fails to retrieve the `MStoKMH` function?

Comment: If you're converting from one unit to another why not have your inner dictionary key be the units you convert to instead of a magic string.

Comment: @juharr is right; what you really want here is a dictionary of the form `(Unit, Unit) --> Func<float, float>` or `Unit --> Unit --> Func<float, float>`.  This business with a string is bizarre.

Answer (score 8):

Declare the MStoKMH and MStoMPH variables *first*.

They're initialized in order when they're all Static like this.  So at the point you create the dictionary, those variables are still null.

From 10.5.5 of the C# Specification:

> Thus, when a class is initialized, all static fields in that class are
>   first initialized to their default values, and then the static field
>   initializers are executed in textual order.

Comment: Even better:  **do the initialization in a static constructor**. Then it becomes crystal clear what order things happen in.